# map/set iterator not incrementable error when I execute the function

Tags: c++, stl

The error occurs when I execute the following functions:
I have checked the iterator, it should be no problem, I think the problem should be the insert and erase but I don't how to fix it

```
     void addNewUser(Records *record) {

         if (mapUser.find(record->getUserName()) != mapUser.end())
             cout << "User Name has been used already!!! " << endl;
         else
            mapUser.insert(pair<string, Records*>(record->getUserName(), record));

     }

     void deleteUser(string key) {
         map<string, Records*>::iterator it = mapUser.find(key);
         map<string, Records*>::iterator end = mapUser.end();

         if (it != end) {
            delete it->second;
            it->second = NULL;
         }
         mapUser.erase(it);

     }
```

The main:

```
int main() {


DataBaseOperation *a = new DataBaseOperation();


DataBaseOperation *a = new DataBaseOperation();

Records *r = new Records(10, 1, "Ben", "Ben Li");
Records *s = new Records(1, 1, "ken", "Ken Lee");


a->addNewUser(r);
a->deleteUser(s->getUserName());

a->displayAll();

delete a;

system("pause");
return 0;}
```

if I call the function like this in my main function:

```
a->displayAll();
cout << endl;

a->addNewUser(r);
cout << endl;

a->displayAll();
cout << endl;

a->deleteUser(s->getUserName());
a->displayAll();
```

it will work fine:
[image]

but if I want to call the functions(addNewUser and deleteUser) individually and when I execute "a->addNewUser(s);" in main, the error will occur.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why do you `new` all over the place? Did you come from Java by any chance? You are probably better off with just `map<string, Record>`. Anyway, you **must not** `erase` the `end` iterator.

Comment: You get the error when you execute *which* function?

Comment: I got error when I execute both addNewUser and deleteUser function

Comment: @BoBTFish I just forgot to delete.

Answer (score 2):

You should call `erase` only if `it` points to an actual element (=not `end`).

> The iterator `pos` must be valid and dereferenceable. Thus the `end()` iterator (which is valid, but is not dereferencable) cannot be used as a value for `pos`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase

Just move the `erase` inside the `if` above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have moved the erase inside the "if " body, but the problem is not solved. I have added more description of the question, can you have a look?